# How do I insert equation numbering in mathtype?

Tags: microsoft-word, mathtype

The \tag syntax works well with jupyter notebook

[image]

However, it causes error with mathtype

[image]

I'm sure that mathtype supports tex/latex/mathjax as it works well with some other mathjax code.

How do I fix the error?

How do I insert equation number in mathtype?

Any other method to insert equation numbering with mathtype is also appreciated.

the numbering and the last line of equation need to be in the same line.